# Change color submenu (dropdown)

Tags: wordpress, colors, menu, dropdown

I need to change the background color of the dropdown menu on my website:

https://institutoschuman.org/

I supposed it was very easy but I'm not able to do it. I've Checked the code of my style.css but I haven't found the lines that determine the color of the dropdown menu. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your style.css with the CSS below and change your background colour from white (#fff) to one you prefer, that should do it.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 0px) {
    .respMenu {
        background: #fff;
    }

    .respMenu a {
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this code doesn't change anything :((

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 0px) {
    .respMenu {
        background: #0095ff !important;
    }

    .respMenu a {
        background: #0095ff !important;
    }
}

Comment: Not sure if you have changed the original lines of css or you are just pasting my code at the bottom of your css file?

Comment: I've add the following code in  the CSS custom code: @media screen and (max-width: 960px) and (min-width: 0px) { .respMenu { background: #0095ff !important; } .respMenu a { background: #0095ff !important; } } Unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
.menu ul.sub-menu, .menu ul.children {
margin-top: 65px;
}

.sub-menu > li {
background: white !important;
}
.sub-menu > li:hover {
background: #fcfcf4 !important;
}
.sub-menu > li > a {
color: black !important;
}
.sub-menu > li > a:hover {
color: #008ddb !important;
}
```